# IIS 8 Exception Filter is not regitered

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have MVC 4 application with error filter to catch all unhandled exceptions.

```
public class GlobalErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        private readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(GlobalErrorHandler));

        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
                return;

            var statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
            {
                statusCode = (filterContext.Exception as HttpException).GetHttpCode();
            }
            else if (filterContext.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                //to prevent login prompt in IIS
                // which will appear when returning 401.
                statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            }

            var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
            var result = new ViewResult
                                    {
                                        ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml",
                                        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                                    };
            filterContext.Result = result;


            logger.Error("Error Controller: " + controllerName + " Action: "+ actionName + "Exception: " + filterContext.Exception.StackTrace);
            // Prepare the response code.
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }
    }
```

Registered as:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new GlobalErrorHandler());
    }
}
```

Theis works as expected(the custom error page is shown) in Visual Studion and on IIS 7.5(Win 7) but on IIS 8.5(Win Server 2012 R2) when some unhandled exception is thrown, the internal server error page is shown. How can I enable the error handler on IIS 8?

Edit: Possible duplicate of [.Net MVC custom error page not working in IIS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502689/net-mvc-custom-error-page-not-working-in-iis8). I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

as said here [.Net MVC custom error page not working in IIS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502689/net-mvc-custom-error-page-not-working-in-iis8) fixed the issue.